# Checking to see if element is visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a list of apps that are listed on a non angular page.  The list of apps that are available depends on what subscription level was paid for.  If the subscription level does not have an app purchased the app is still listed however there is an overlay over the app. (please see picture).

[image]

The html looks like this:

```html
<div class="apps-item apps-no-border disabled">
  <div class="apps-name">
    <span>Interactive Event Diagrams</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divider">
    <div class="apps-description">Interactive Event Diagrams is an indispensable online tool, allowing website visitors to view your meeting rooms and create their own customized event layouts according to their specific needs, all while using your venue’s available inventory. Users
      can email and save diagrams or images for future reference.</div>
    <div class="apps-image-preview">
      <img alt="Interactive Event Diagrams" src="/Content/Images/AppsPreview/interactive_event_diagrams.png">
    </div>
    <div class="apps-action">Not Purchased</div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if an app is purchased the overlay element is shaded gray in the html and is not view-able on screen.  (Ex. no grey shading over Hotel Venue Explorer) I want to be able to check and see if the overlay is seen or not seen.

I've tried this:

```js
elm = element.all(by.css('div.apps-item')).get(5);
expect(elm.$('div.overlay').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

However the expect is returning false.
Other apps html, notice the grey over the overlay class

[image: Other apps html, notice the grey over the overlay class]

Comment: shouldn't you just check if the element `hasClass('overlay')`?

Comment: @dcohenb They both have the class in the html. I added a picture of what the other apps html looks like.

Comment: Your `div.overlay` will always be in DOM all the time, but its being altered using css and javascript based on the subscription level. Is that right? For ex - apply div.overlay for one kind of subscription level and don't apply it if the subscription is present. Or is it being removed from DOM if its not needed for that particular div.apps-item? Thanks

Comment: @Girish Right. Due to the overlay I cannot click on the box to use the app.  I just need to make it so my test says ok this person has 'select' subscription. Can they click on apps they don't have access to, no. Is it shaded yes.  Can they click on apps they do have access to, yes. Is it shaded no.

Comment: Ok, so you are checking if **5th apps-item element(Interactive event Diagrams)** has the div.overlay on it and its returning false always. If yes, then your code shows you are accessing the 6th element. Try this - `elm = element.all(by.css('div.apps-item')).get(4);
expect(elm.$('div.overlay').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();`. `get()` function is a zero based index. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Girish I am checking the 6th app

Comment: @Girish really it changes as I have to check each subscription.  I know the array starts at 0 and so forth. Perhaps I need to get the webelement?

Comment: Do you ever get true result for `expect(elm.$('div.overlay').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();` ? I don't think we can automate it by checking whether its displayed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `div.overlay` is always present in the DOM, then its hard to check if its displayed because it will always be there in the DOM and your css and javascript might be handling the display property(like add overlay if its needed or don't add when its not needed). Also checking isDisplayed function for an empty html element doesn't work as far as i know.

In order to verify it you can check for css attributes that are responsible for the greying out functionality. Here's how -

```
elm = element.all(by.css('div.apps-item')).get(5);
//Use your css attribute that greys the apps-item div like height, width, color, etc...
expect(elm.$('div.overlay').getCssValue('background-color')).toEqual('grey'); 
expect(elm.$('div.overlay').getCssValue('width')).not.toBeNull(); //If you know the width then you can check for equality or greaterThan(someVal).
expect(elm.$('div.overlay').getCssValue('height')).not.toBeNull();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not getting any color back with that, I only get null

Comment: I would recommend trying `expect(element(by.className('overlay')).getCssValue('background-color')).toEqual('grey');` and see if that returns the proper value.

Comment: Right i forgot to correct it, thanks John. Updated my code @NicolePhillips. Since the css values will be the one's controlling the properties of the div, we should be getting the css values.

Comment: @Girish the Css value did work, I had unchecked as I was i did research and found that out before you changed your answer.  I will make adjustment.  I did have an issue that I had to set my .get(5 -1) Where 5 is actually a variable.